# why is TableB got coverd by Table A when copy and paste with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy two tables from Excel to word with VBA. And I only want the table start from sheet 4 until used sheet. Why the result only have Table A? I stoped the code to see the procedure of copying and paste, the Program showed it copy Table B firstly and then copy Table A, but Table A cover Table B, there is only Table A in the end. The code is as bellow.

```
        ElseIf InStr(1, info(i).tag, ".xlsx", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '       Insert the Excel table
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim ii
For ii = 1 To ThisDocument.Tables.Count
ThisDocument.Tables(ii).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
Next
         Selection.Font.Bold = True
         Selection.TypeText (vbCrLf & totalct & ". " & info(i).cap & vbCrLf)
         Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
         Dim src As Excel.Workbook
         Dim ws As Worksheet
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
         Set src = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strfpath & info(i).tag, ReadOnly:=True)
         oExcel.Visible = False
         For j = 4 To src.Worksheets.Count
         src.Worksheets(j).UsedRange.Copy
         Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
         Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
         Selection.TypeText (vbCrLf)
         Next
         Set ws = Nothing
         Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
         totalct = totalct - 1

    End If
End If
i = i - 1
```

Wend

Comment: Maybe not covering but replacing.

Comment: you are pasting a table into the document while the previous table is selected

Comment: How should l fix it? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: try using `wdmove` instead of `wdextend`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It really works !!! Appreciate!

Comment: Can l ask one more thing? How should l run the code at a Bookmark named 'chapter'? l have tried :Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="chapter"   but it still paste at the beginning of the document. Thanks for your help!